# replace without using a dot how to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following code, but I want to replace it without a dot

nominal without separator

```js
function convertToRupiah(angka){
    var rupiah = '';    
    var angkarev = angka.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
      
    for(var i = 0; i < angkarev.length; i++) 
        if(i%3 == 0) rupiah += angkarev.substr(i,3)+'.';
      
    return rupiah.split('',rupiah.length-1).reverse().join('');
}
  
function showkerugian(str) {
      var temuan = str.replace(/\./g, "",); // update pattern to regex in order to replace all `.` occurrences

      $('#nilai_potensi_kerugian').val(convertToRupiah(temuan));
};
    
$('input#nilai_temuan') .on('keyup focusin focusout ', function(event) {
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
              .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" oninput="showkerugian(this.value)" class="form-control nominal" id="nilai_temuan" name="nilai_temuan" >
<input type="text" class="form-control nominal" name="nilai_potensi_kerugian" id="nilai_potensi_kerugian" readonly>
```

can you solve the problem, help me

[image]

Comment: Can you include a sample of the input and what you want the result to be like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the input to contain dots and the output to not have any:

```js
function convertToRupiah(angka){
    var rupiah = '';    
    var angkarev = angka.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
      
    for(var i = 0; i < angkarev.length; i++) 
        if(i%3 == 0) rupiah += angkarev.substr(i,3);
      
    return rupiah.split('',rupiah.length).reverse().join('');
}
  
function showkerugian(str) {
      var temuan = str.replace(/\./g, "",); // update pattern to regex in order to replace all `.` occurrences

      $('#nilai_potensi_kerugian').val(convertToRupiah(temuan));
};
    
$('input#nilai_temuan') .on('keyup focusin focusout ', function(event) {
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
              .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" oninput="showkerugian(this.value)" class="form-control nominal" id="nilai_temuan" name="nilai_temuan" >
<input type="text" class="form-control nominal" name="nilai_potensi_kerugian" id="nilai_potensi_kerugian" readonly>
```

The issue was that on this line
`if(i%3 == 0) rupiah += angkarev.substr(i,3)+'.';` you added a "."

Comment: Why is the nominal amount different?

Comment: Check my answer again, you subtracted the length - 1, I removed that bit as well.

Comment: what if foreach?

Comment: Can you be more specific by what you mean? For each what?

Comment: check the picture above, when I save the data stored only one data is the other one becomes null.
how about using foreach?